# What does the question mean by suppressing some terms?

Tags: contest-math

[image: Problem]
I don’t really understand what it means by suppressing some terms. Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: I think "suppress" means "omit" in this context. See what happens when $m=n=2$.

Comment: In other words prove there exist some sets $\emptyset \subsetneq \{x_\alpha, ....,x_\omega\}\subsetneq \{x_1, ...., x_n\}$ and $\emptyset \subsetneq \{y_\alpha, ....,y_\psi\}\subsetneq \{y_1, ...., y_m\}$ so that $x_\alpha + .... +x_\omega = y_\alpha + .... +y_\psi$.   Except my way of stating it is far too convoluted for its simple concept.

Comment: As an aside, this is a common (de)skinning of PGP, which seems complicated at first but is quite easy if you know the idea. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728897/combinatorics-problem-about-weight-of-balls-posn-camp-2/3728984#3728984) for more details.